# Text files handles differently

Tags: text-files, ado

I am trying to read from a csv.txt file using Ado Recordset
I get no results back when trying..
When I copy the contents of the original file into a new text file, and read from that file, it works just fine.

Any ideas what the reason for this might be?

The second file is smaller in size, about 1/2. That's the only difference I can see. This is driving me mad :-)

'Edit
Update with code & schema.ini

Code:

```
Sub ImportTextFiles()
    Dim objAdoDbConnection As ADODB.Connection
    Dim objAdoDbRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strAdodbConnection As String
    Dim pathSource As String
    Dim filename As String

    pathSource = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Reports\"
    filename = "test1.txt"
    'filename = "test2.txt"

    strAdodbConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                        & "Data Source=" & pathSource _
                        & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=yes;FMT=Delimited"";"

    Set objAdoDbConnection = CreateObject("Adodb.Connection")
    Set objAdoDbRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    With objAdoDbConnection
        .Open (strAdodbConnection)
        With objAdoDbRecordset
             .Open "Select top 10 * FROM " & filename & " WHERE [Date] > #01/01/2000# ", objAdoDbConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
            If Not objAdoDbRecordset.EOF Then objAdoDbRecordset.MoveFirst
                Do While Not objAdoDbRecordset.EOF
                    Debug.Print "Field(0): " & objAdoDbRecordset(0).Value
                    objAdoDbRecordset.MoveNext
            Loop
            .Close
        End With
        .Close
    End With

    Set objAdoDbRecordset = Nothing
    Set objAdoDbConnection = Nothing
End Sub

Schema.ini:
[Test1.txt]
col1=date text
col2=interval integer
col3=application text
[Test2.txt]
col1=date text
col2=interval integer
col3=application text
```

Comment: Without seeing code, it's hard to say. Look into permissions on each file. Also naming. Did you spell it correctly? Including cases? Are there any other differences between the two files?

Comment: Could also be a problem with character encoding.

Comment: how would I find out the actual encoding of the file @ CBroe?

Answer (score 0):

notepadd++ gave me the answer, file1 is ucs-2 encoded, the newly created utf-8